# code execution using if elif statement

Tags: python-3.x

interface port-channel 1
ALLOWED_VLAN 2,4-7,27,30-31,38-39,41-42,48-50
ALLOWED_VLAN 74,678,1101-1102,1201-1202
interface port-channel 2
ALLOWED_VLAN 37,51-73,75-76,1051-1052,2001
interface port-channel 101
ALLOWED_VLAN 10,18-19,37,39,51-52,75-76,901-902
ALLOWED_VLAN 2901-2902,3204,3305

```
import re
import itertools
fileOpen3 = open('C:\\Python36\\execrice\\inter.txt')
list3 = []
for line in fileOpen3.readlines():
    if line.startswith('ALLOWED_VLAN'):
        allowedVlan = re.compile(r'\d+\S+')
        list1 = allowedVlan.findall(line)
        st1 = list1[0]
        pv1 = st1.split(',')
        list3.append(pv1)
        merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list3))
        singleVlanDigit = []
        expandedVlan1 = []
        for i in merged:
            rangeOfVlan = []
            if '-' in i:
                rangeOfVlan.append(i)
            else:
                singleVlanDigit.append(i)
                singleVlanDigit = list(map(int,singleVlanDigit))
            for j in rangeOfVlan:
                l = j.split('-')
                startVlan = int(l[0])
                endVlan = int(l[1])
                for k in range(startVlan,endVlan):
                    expandedVlan1.append(k)
        vlanallowed = singleVlanDigit + expandedVlan1
        vlanallowed = list(map(int,vlanallowed))
        print (vlanallowed)
    elif line.startswith('interface port-channel'):
        list3=[]
        print ("interface port-channel")
fileOpen3.close()
```

my program combines all the digits in one single list where as i want it to stop when it reads the "interface port-channel 2" and so on

i want the output of this program to be as below

interface port-channel
[2, 27, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49, 74, 678, 1101, 1201]
interface port-channel
[37, 2001, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 1051]
interface port-channel
[10, 37, 39, 18, 51, 75, 901, 3204, 3305, 2901]

but it produces the below output

interface port-channel
[2, 27, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49]
[2, 27, 74, 678, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49, 1101, 1201]
interface port-channel
[2, 27, 74, 678, 37, 2001, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49, 1101, 1201, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 1051]
interface port-channel
[2, 27, 74, 678, 37, 2001, 10, 37, 39, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49, 1101, 1201, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 1051, 18, 51, 75, 901]
[2, 27, 74, 678, 37, 2001, 10, 37, 39, 3204, 3305, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49, 1101, 1201, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 1051, 18, 51, 75, 901, 2901]

after reinitialising the list3 in elif block as suggested by Boar i got the below results which is very to my end results

interface port-channel
[2, 27, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49]
[2, 27, 74, 678, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49, 1101, 1201]
interface port-channel
[37, 2001, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 1051]
interface port-channel
[10, 37, 39, 18, 51, 75, 901]
[10, 37, 39, 3204, 3305, 18, 51, 75, 901, 2901]

but i want the results to be like this

interface port-channel
[2, 27, 74, 678, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49, 1101, 1201]
interface port-channel
[37, 2001, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 1051]
interface port-channel
[10, 37, 39, 3204, 3305, 18, 51, 75, 901, 2901]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've had to guess at where the line breaks fall in your data but I think I have it right.

The repeated data is because you are initializing `list3` in the wrong place. It should be after `if line.startswith('ALLOWED_VLAN'):`

With that fix, your program does this:

```
interface port-channel
[2, 27, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49]
[74, 678, 1101, 1201]
interface port-channel
[37, 2001, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 1051]
interface port-channel
[10, 37, 39, 18, 51, 75, 901]
[3204, 3305, 2901]
```

which is close to what you want. You just need to combine the lists of integers before printing them. Combine the values of `vnlanallowed` in the `if` part of the loop, then print it out and reinitialize it in the `elif` part.

To get the exact format of the output you want, you need to wait until you know you have all of the lists of port-channel numbers before printing them. You only know that when you see a new list start, or you reach end-of-file.

```
import re
import itertools
fileOpen3 = open(r'E:\...\inter.txt')
channel_list = []
for line in fileOpen3.readlines():
    if line.startswith('ALLOWED_VLAN'):
        list3 = []
        allowedVlan = re.compile(r'\d+\S+')
        list1 = allowedVlan.findall(line)
        st1 = list1[0]
        pv1 = st1.split(',')
        list3.append(pv1)
        merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list3))
        singleVlanDigit = []
        expandedVlan1 = []
        for i in merged:
            rangeOfVlan = []
            if '-' in i:
                rangeOfVlan.append(i)
            else:
                singleVlanDigit.append(i)
                singleVlanDigit = list(map(int,singleVlanDigit))
            for j in rangeOfVlan:
                l = j.split('-')
                startVlan = int(l[0])
                endVlan = int(l[1])
                for k in range(startVlan,endVlan):
                    expandedVlan1.append(k)
        vlanallowed = singleVlanDigit + expandedVlan1
        vlanallowed = list(map(int,vlanallowed))
        #print (vlanallowed)
        channel_list.extend(vlanallowed)
    elif line.startswith('interface port-channel'):
        if channel_list:
            print ("interface port-channel", channel_list)
        channel_list = []
print("interface port-channel", channel_list)
fileOpen3.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted it to combine the 2 list together and want an output like below interface port-channel
[2, 27, 4, 5, 6, 30, 38, 41, 48, 49,74, 678, 1101, 1201]
interface port-channel
[37, 2001, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 1051]
interface port-channel
[10, 37, 39, 18, 51, 75, 901,3204, 3305, 2901]